# Kotlin - Como puedo actualizar la ubicación cada 5 minutos

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Tengo una app que una vez que se conecta el usuario su ubicación al moverse se actualiza **pero ahora necesito se guarde cada 5 minutos** con bd en firebase y trabajo en android studio.

Código:

```
private fun connectDriver() {  /// se detecta la ubicacion del user
    //Creamos el Timer
       
    val timer = Timer()
        
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(object : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            val date = Date()
            easyWayLocation?.endUpdates() // OTROS HILOS DE EJECUCION
            easyWayLocation?.startLocation()  

            //La función que queremos ejecutar
            geoFirestore.setLocation(idDriver, GeoPoint(position.latitude, position.longitude))
            Log.d( ModalBottomSheetBooking.TAG,
                    "hora  $date"
                )
        }
    }, 60000, 60000)
    showButtonDisconnect()
}
```